# Multiple URL's in a cell in Data Studio shows as one combined URL

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, looker-studio

I have a Data Studio Dashboard that shows the upload URL from a file that was uploaded through Google Forms. So the user can click on the URL on Data Studio to see which file was uploaded. But when multiple files are uploaded then it shows all the URL's back to back in one cell like this: **https://drive.google.com/example, https://drive.google.com/example** and when the user clicks on them then they get an error because Data Studio makes them one combined URL.

I created a field with a HYPERLINK formula but this gave me the same result as it combines both URL's into one hyperlink. Is there a Data Studio formula that can create 2 separate links or is there a way to separate the URL's at sheet level maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Limit the Upload to 1 file seems to be the only option